# If I use a normal build of ffmpeg how take advantage of video acceleration for scale?

Tags: ffmpeg, transcoding, filter

I generally use ffmpeg for encode in h264 and also resize media

My common command is something like:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -b:v 5000k -s:v 1280x720 out.mov
```

I have an Nvidia GeForce 1060 card.

I also use the Zeranoe Builds or various generated with the crosscompile scripts (but i'm not very pro with it)

What i would like to know is:

1) It is possible to SCALE for example from 4k or FHD (1080p) to HD (720p) by taking advantage of GPU acceleration instead of using the normal SCALE ? It is possible also to specify if use bicubic, bilinear and so on?

2) It is possible to encode in h264 faster by taking advantage of GPU acceleration ?

And what syntax/options to specify in ffmpeg to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your second question is yes. Change `-c:v libx264` to `-c:v h264_nvenc`.  I use those builds as well.  If you use the option `-encoders` you can see a list of included video and audio codecs. 
[This](https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/4b49f463a08377530df6cecb8171306a) is a good resource for encoding with FFMPEG.

**See the warning on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44510765/gpu-accelerated-video-processing-with-ffmpeg) if you try this**